# Circular list detection in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, circular-list

Is there a way to detect the first element of a circular list in Python? In Java and C++ you can just establish a pointer to the first element.

Question I came across: Given a circular linked list, implement an algorithm which returns the node at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't circularity imply that the notion of "first" is entirely symmetric and thus kinda meaningless? Of course, I guess you could implement a data element to determine which node is the "head"

Comment: The accustomed situation should be: given a reference to a node of a singly linked list, find a circle, if any, and the node first reached therein from the reference given (which may refer to a node outside the circle).

Comment: The low-level data structure *linked list* isn't (directly) related to the high-level Python `list` data structure. CPython might use linked lists internally, but that's something entirely different from the `list` in the Python language (which is more like a dynamic array). So what exactly do you mean by "circular list"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: if you traverse the list, it's the first element you will encounter twice. it's well defined.

Comment: In other languages the concept of a "circular list" means a symmetric list. But say there are repeating elements. Then encountering an element twice does nothing. So how do you find the specific FIRST node, or the same node again after traversing the whole circular list and returning to the starting place...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: But that is extremely sensitive to where in the circle you start. The results therefore, are unstable and not reproducible

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: In that case, you're talking about a linked list with a loop in it (which is indeed a classic interview question), not a circular (or circularly linked) list, which was my interpretation of OP's question from `circular linked list`

Comment: @SarahMarkers: elements stored *in* a node can be repeating. but the *nodes* themselves are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circular linked list has no true beginning & end. But from your comment, I think you want to detect when you reach the element you started with while looping through the list.

```
#The structure of ListNode
class ListNode:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None

# Supposes you have a circular linked list and you have a reference to head. You can do as follows to print the whole list. 
current = head.next
while current != head: # stop when it comes back to head
  print current.val
  current = current.next
```

Comment: this is incorrect. you assume the list links back to the *first* element.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath By the definition of circular linked list. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_vs._linearly_linked
It's not a linked list with a loop, it's a circular linked list.

Comment: What OP says - "So how do you find the specific FIRST node, or the same node again after traversing the whole circular list and returning to the starting place". Also - "In Java and C++ you can just establish a pointer to the first element."

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a depth first search to answer this in generality, here's the sort of thing:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a[1] = b
b[2] = a

def is_list(l):
    try:
        it = iter(l)
        return l
    except TypeError:
        return None

def dfs(a, colors):
    l = is_list(a)
    print 'is_list:', l
    if l:
        if colors.has_key(id(l)):
            print 'cycle detected'
            return l
        colors[id(l)] = ''
        for ll in l:
            dfs(ll, colors)

colors = {}
dfs(a, colors)
```